# Have a comma followed by a space with componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: objective-c

I have multiple values pulling from a database that are outputted on a section of an app. Basically how they read now is like this-
Brand: Option 1,Option 2,Option 3,etc

What I would like is to have the separator be a comma and then a space so it will look like this-
Brand: Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, etc

Here is the code I currently have:

```
NSArray * arrayColor = [[_product_modal valueForKey:@"colorCodes"] 
componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 1):

Join your components using `@", "`:

```
NSArray *arrayColor = [[_product_modal valueForKey:@"colorCodes"]
                        componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *result = [arrayColor componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple string replacement:

```
NSString *noSpaceString = @"Brand: Option 1,Option 2,Option 3,etc.";
NSString *spaceString = [noSpaceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@", "];
```

No need to split into an array and recombine.